# TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)?

Tags: python-3.x

Im having trouble with My Packet sending code, I exported my older code from an older version of python to python 3. I get a TypeError: an integer is required (got type str) error and I dont know how to fix it.

```
import socket
import random
import time

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

bytes = random._urandom(1024)

ip = int(input('Target ip:'))
port = int(input('port:'))
duration = int(input('number of seconds to send packets: '))
timeout = time.time() + float(duration)
sent = 0
while True:
    if time.time() > timeout:
        break
    else:
        pass
    sock.sendto(bytes,(ip,port))
    sent = sent + 1
    print ("sent %s packets to %s through port %s")%(sent, ip, port)
```

Im new to this forum so sorry in advance.

Heres my full traceback

```
    Target ip:157.240.22.35:
port:8080
number of seconds to send packets: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 119, in <module>
    vspd.debug(filename, port_num, debug_id, debug_options, run_as)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\debugger.py", line 37, in debug
    run(address, filename, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_local.py", line 48, in run_file
    run(argv, addr, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_local.py", line 99, in _run
    _pydevd.main()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1734, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1079, in run
    return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1086, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 25, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:\Users\nikit\source\repos\PythonApplication2\PythonApplication2\PythonApplication2.py", line 19, in <module>
    sock.sendto(bytes,(ip,port))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what to fix to solve the TypeError: an integer is required - got type str](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49929434/62576)

Comment: Sorry, your code actually looks fine. A full trace will be helpful

Comment: `print ("sent %s packets to %s through port %s" % (sent, ip, port))`

Comment: This line doesn't run on python 3.6 (tested). I got confused earlier because I ran it from python 2 previously

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ip`, `port` and `duration` must be int values I suppose.
So, this should resolve it -

```
ip = input('Target ip:')
port = int(input('port:'))
duration = int(input('number of seconds to send packets: '))
```

Comment: I know get a new error when I type in an example Ip adress. whilst using your solution for integer I get this when I input my an Ip when I run it.          
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "python", line 9, in <module>
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '157.240.22.35:'

Comment: Sorry, earlier I converted IP to `int`, it should be `str`, so shouldn't be casted. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `port` item in the address tuple for the `socket.sendto()` method has to be an integer according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-families), so you should convert the returning value of `input()` for `port` to an integer:

```
port = int(input('port:'))
```